# Functions of a class vba

Tags: excel, vba, function, class

I am building a class that has a bunch of Dictionaries that store a bunch of column data. Depending on parameters, the dictionaries are printed a little differently. I created functions within the class to print the data to another sheet.
Here is the class

```
Sub Export()
'Finding next available cell
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
End With
nextrow = LastRow + 1

For i = 1 To Me.BatchNo.Count

    If Me.Location(i) <> "A_REF   " Or Me.Location(i) <> "B_REF   " Then
        Me.NotRef(i,nextrow) 'Syntax Error HERE!!!
    Else
        Me.IsRef(i,nextrow)  'Syntax Error HERE!!!

nextrow = nextrow + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

And here are the function calls

`Function NotRef(i As Integer, nextrow As Integer)`

`Function IsRef(i As Integer, nextrow As Integer)`

All the functions do it print the saved data but i get a "Syntax Error" when i call them. Am i calling them wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit rusty on VBA but I believe you cannot call Functions c/c++/c# style, which allow you to ignore the return value.  A VBA function returns a value and you must therefore provide a variable to receive it.  Either that or change the Functions to Subs, in which case, if I remember correctly, you will need to remove the parentheses.

CORRECTION You can ignore the return value in VBA, by treating the function as if it were a Sub, by removing the parentheses.  (Thanks to @Sam)

HTH